# How do I insert an ClassName[] Array into an arraylist of the same ClassName?

Tags: java

Im trying to add an Array of Classname[] into an ArrayList. But i get this error:
**"The method add(FacturacionClass) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (FacturacionClass[])"**

Here is the ArrayList and the insertion constructor ive tried.

```
ArrayList<FacturacionClass> FacturacionData = new ArrayList<FacturacionClass>();
```

Constructor:

```
FacturacionClass(String clientName, String clientID, FacturacionClass[] array, int cantProd){
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.clientId = clientID;
    FacturacionData.add(array);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified `FacturacionData` to hold elements of type `FacturacionClass`, so naturally you cannot add an array of `FacturacionClass` to it.

Rather you probably want [ArrayList.addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-).

```
FacturacionData.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Nice, Thank you It worked, but what if I wanted to print the content of the Array once its inside the ArrayList?
The constructor for the items in the Array is
`FacturacionClass(String productID, Double productPrice)`

Comment: The items in the array are added individually to the `FacturacionData` ArrayList. You would iterate over that ArrayList and print the values. It will help if `FacturacionClass` provides a meaningful override of `toString`.

Comment: Oh, i see, the thing i want is, one array per space in the ArrayList, every array is different from the one before. So it is not one spread across all the ArrayList.

Comment: Then you need something like `ArrayList<ArrayList< FacturacionClass>> FacturacionData`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FacturacionData.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

`Arrays.asList()` method produces an unmodifiable list, so you will not be able to add any new element to it.